# Get correct path in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Does Node.js have a URL module to resolve this?

```
getCorrectUrl('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', '../../img/some.jpg'); // http://www.domain.com/img/some.jpg
getCorrectUrl('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', './img/some.jpg'); // http://www.domain.com/img/some.jpg
getCorrectUrl('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', 'http://www.domain.com/img/some.jpg'); // http://www.domain.com/img/some.jpg
getCorrectUrl('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', '../img/some.jpg'); // http://www.domain.com/folder/img/some.jpg
getCorrectUrl('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', 'img/some.jpg'); // http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/img/some.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the native [URL](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module. What you'd be looking for is `url.resolve()`.

```
url.resolve('http://www.domain.com/folder/folder/', '../img/some.jpg');
// http://www.domain.com/folder/img/some.jpg
```